# ¿Compar números de un array con condiciones?

Tags: java, array, condiciones

Muy buenas necesito hacer lo siguiente:

El código en en Java

Realizar un programa que determine de un conjunto de 10 números enteros, introducidos por teclado, cuántos son menores que 18, cuántos mayores de 65 y cuántos están comprendidos entre 15 y 65.

Hasta ahora lo tengo avanzado de esta manera:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GrupoNumeros {
    public static void main (String [] args){
                        
        System.out.println("Bienvenido a comparador de números");
        
        int i; //Variable que luego inicializaremos para racorrer el array.
        int contador = 0;
        int[] numeros = new int[10]; //creamos un array de 10 posiciones.

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(i=0; i<numeros.length; i++) //El 1er número se guardará en la memoria 0, pero nos mostrará que es la pos gracias al i+1 siguiente.
        {
            System.out.printf("Introduzca número %d: ", i+1); //%d es un formato que crece según crece i y tomaese valor.
            System.out.println();
            numeros[i] = teclado.nextInt(); //leémos cada número introducido y lo almacenamos el arrya creado.
        }
                     
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Tamaño del array: " + numeros.length);//Imprime el tamaño del array.
        System.out.println();
        
        for(i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
            if (numeros [i] < 16){
                contador ++;
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Losn números menores de 16 son: " + contador + ",");
            }
        }
        
        for(i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
            if (numeros [i] > 65){
                
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Los números mayores de 65, son: " + numeros [i]);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El caso es que la salida de los dos for que tengo para comparar si tengo números menores de 16 y mayores de 65, me lo presentan en líneas, y me gustaria tenerlo en la misma linea con los números listados.

Y el punto de ¿Qué números hay entre 16 y 65? no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Comment: crea las variables contador fuera del for y tras los 2 for haces el Print tengo +contador numeros menores de 16 y tengo +contandor2 numeros mayores de 65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo lo puedes resolver con un mismo **ciclo for**:

```
int contMenores16 = 0;
int contMayores65 = 0;
int contEntre16y65 = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
{
    if(numeros[i] < 16)
    {
        contMenores16++;
    }

    if(numeros[i] > 65)
    {
        contMayores65++;
    }

    if(numeros[i] >= 16 && numeros[i] <= 65)
    {
        contEntre16y65++;
    } 
}

System.out.println(contMenores16.toString());
System.out.println(contEntre16y65.toString());
System.out.println(contMayores65.toString());
```

Primero declaro las **variables contadoras** que me van a servir para contar los rangos que deseas. Posteriormente hago un **ciclo for** y pregunto si cada elemento del arreglo se encuentra entre los rangos que deseas, si se encuentra en alguno de esos rangos pues se incrementa la variable correspondiente.

Por último se imprimen las **variables contadoras** por cada rango.

Para saber si un número se encuentra entre **16** y **65** se usa:

```
if(numeros[i] >= 16 && numeros[i] <= 65)
```

Donde **&&** es un **operador lógico** que representa el **and lógico**, lo cual quiere decir que deben cumplirse las dos condiciones: **numeros[i] >= 16 **y** numeros[i] <= 65**.

Por último **>=**(Mayor o igual) es un **operador relacional** que indica si **numeros[i]** es mayor o igual que el número por el que estás comparando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, bien explicado como un profesor.
Tu respuesta me ha sido de mucha ayuda.

Gracias de nuevo

Answer (score -1):

Declaras tres variables

```
 Int contador1 = 0, int contador2=0, int contador3 = 0

  // Dentro del for haz las siguientes validacionez
   If(numeros[i] >= 65){
   Contador1++;
    }
   if else(numeros[i] > 18 &&  numeros[i] < 65){
  Contador2++;
   }
   Else{
   Contador3++;
   }


  Fuera del for
   System.out.print(contador1);
    System.out.print(contador2);
    System.out.print(contador3);
```